# Count in an array the number for each same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

My function is

```
       var MyArray= [];
        $('input:checked').each(function(index) {
            MyArray= ($(this).attr('id') + ":" + $(this).val()).length;
        });
```

My array is

```
Array [ "1:R1", "2:R2", "3:R3", "4:R1" ]
```

I would like to count the differents values and to get this object

```
Object {R1:2, R2:1, R3:1}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what is $('input:checked') doing. Can you show us some markup? It seems there is more going on here than what you are telling us.

Comment: The OP is looping through checked inputs to count them by value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the values in an array and then get the values out of the array to process them and create an object, put them in the object to start with:

```
var map = {};
$('input:checked').each(function() {
  var key = $(this).val();
  if (key in map) {
    map[key]++;
  } else {
    map[key] = 1;
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/0a35c6yp/

Comment: thansk so much !! it's exactly I need !

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your var with this code :

```
var arr = [ "1:R1", "2:R2", "3:R3", "4:R1" ];

var obj = {};

for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i++) {
  var parts = arr[i].split(':');
  if(parts.length > 1) {
    if(!obj[parts[1]]) {
      obj[parts[1]] = 0;
    }
    obj[parts[1]]++
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Or create directly the correct object :

```
var obj = {};

$('input:checked').each(function (index) {
  var key = $(this).val();
  if (!obj[key]) {
    obj[key] = 0;
  }
  obj[key]++
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to capture the correct portion of the string, and add them as keys to the object, incrementing the value if it already exists:

```
var regex = /\d+:(R\d+)/
var obj = {};
arr.forEach(function (el) {
    var key = el.match(regex)[1];
    if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = 0;
    obj[key]++;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/92yqyp2n/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:
Write your Array into a Map and step up your value each time your map already knows the key.

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  var entry = myArray[i];
  var key = entry.split(":")[1];

  if(myMap.has(key))
      myMap.set(key, myMap.get(key) + 1);
  else
      myMap.set(key, 1);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/karixuyitu/2/edit?html,js,output)